# Different types of carbides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ions

I am confused between different types of carbides such as

$\ce{CaC2}$, $\ce{Mg2C3}$, $\ce{Al4C3}$, $\ce{BaC2}$ or $\ce{BeC2}$.

And if they are different, why they are called carbides?

Comment: Could you expand a little? Is there anything in particular associated with this set of carbides that is causing your confusion? Otherwise I have to admit I can't really see what you are asking - They are called carbides because they are a binary compound of carbon and a more electropositive element, but I feel that this is not really what you want to know

Comment: @IanBush actually I want to know whic carbide on hydrolysis produces which product

Comment: Strongly related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34099/why-do-different-elements-form-different-types-of-carbides

Comment: BaC2 and CaC2  on hydrolysis gives C2H2    Mg2C3 givesC3H4   Al4C3 and Be2C gives CH4

Answer (score 1):

Carbides are a specific class of carbon-containing compound; there is not a single compound called "carbide".  According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbide):

> In chemistry, a carbide is a compound composed of carbon and a less
>   electronegative element. Carbides can be generally classified by
>   chemical bonding type as follows: (i) salt-like, (ii) covalent
>   compounds, (iii) interstitial compounds, and (iv) "intermediate"
>   transition metal carbides. Examples include calcium carbide
>   ($\ce{CaC2}$), silicon carbide ($\ce{SiC}$), tungsten carbide
>   ($\ce{WC}$) (often called simply carbide when referring to machine
>   tooling), and cementite ($\ce{Fe3C}$), each used in key industrial
>   applications. The naming of ionic carbides is not systematic.

Comment: How to know which carbide on hydrolysis produces which product

Comment: @hey You should edit your question to actually *ask* that.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon so what should I do now

Comment: @hey , I agree with pentavalentcarbon that your comment is a separate question. I think a cleaner solution than editing the question at this point is to follow the [guidelines](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for an answered question (it's your question, you get to choose what to do with an answer), then just ask a separate separate question. Be sure that you include all other details you would like to know regarding the topic so that you don't have to keep asking related questions. Also, if you edit your question, my answer becomes deficient unless I delete/modify it.