# Is lithium carbide an ionic compound or covalent?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

I read in my chemistry textbook that lithium carbide (Li4C) is the only carbide amongst alkali metals. As we know, carbides are ionic compounds, and calcium carbide is predominantly ionic (calcium having similar electronegativity value to lithium). 
So, is the bond between lithium and carbon ionic? Or is it covalent?

Does a Li4C exist? If so, what is it's nature?

Comment: Which [lithium carbide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_carbide), Li2C2? You can treat it as more ionic then covalent.

Comment: Do you mean an illusive $\mbox{Li}_4 \mbox{C}$?

Comment: Yes, I mean the Li4C .

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34099/why-do-different-elements-form-different-types-of-carbides